# Why does (Haskell) Repa use only one CPU?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, repa

I have been working on a pathtracer using the `Repa` library. I recently refactored it to incorporate parallelism by using the monadic `computeP`. However, I found that the performance increases were negligible. Moreover, monitoring `htop`, it seemed like the program was still only using one CPU. To drill down on the problem, I opened `ghci` and ran the following:

```
~
❯ stack ghci --package repa
Configuring GHCi with the following packages: 
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /tmp/ghci12667/ghci-script
Prelude> import Data.Array.Repa
Prelude Data.Array.Repa> import System.Random
Prelude Data.Array.Repa System.Random> randomList = randoms (mkStdGen 0)
Prelude Data.Array.Repa System.Random> shape = (Z :. 1000000)
Prelude Data.Array.Repa System.Random> array = fromFunction shape $ \(Z :. i) -> randomList !! i
Prelude Data.Array.Repa System.Random> sumP array
```

No dice. `repa` still seems to use only one CPU core as indicated by `htop`:

[image]

Moreover, execution team barely varies between `sumP` and `sumS`, slightly favoring `sumS`:

```
Prelude Data.Array.Repa System.Random> array = fromListUnboxed (Z :. 1000000) $ take 1000000 $ randoms (mkStdGen 0)
(0.01 secs, 0 bytes)
Prelude Data.Array.Repa System.Random> sumP array
AUnboxed Z [500140.92257232184]
(0.99 secs, 1,916,158,952 bytes)
Prelude Data.Array.Repa System.Random> sumS array
AUnboxed Z [500140.92257232184]
(0.93 secs, 2,348,156,248 bytes)
```

What am I missing? In case it matters, I am using Arch Linux:

```
~
❯ uname -a
Linux roskolnikov 4.11.9-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 5 18:23:08 CEST 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

## Update

Some of the comments indicate that I should use the `-threaded` option for `ghci` as indicated in the `repa` docs. I was under the (mis?)impression that `ghci` used `-threaded` by default. In any case, my program was already using these flags -- this is the snippet from the `.cabal` file:

```
executable write
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             Write.hs
  ghc-options:         -Odph 
                       -rtsopts 
                       -threaded 
                       -fno-liberate-case 
                       -funfolding-use-threshold1000 
                       -funfolding-keeness-factor1000 
                       -fllvm 
                       -optlo-O3
  build-depends:       base 
                     , pathtracer
                     , repa
                     , JuicyPixels
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Moreover, I reran the commands in `ghci` using (I think) the correct ghci options:

```
~
❯ stack ghci\
 --package repa\
 --ghc-options -Odph\
 --ghc-options -rtsopts\
 --ghc-options -with-rtsopts=-N\
 --ghc-options -threaded\
 --ghc-options -fno-liberate-case\
 --ghc-options -funfolding-use-threshold1000\
 --ghc-options -funfolding-keeness-factor1000\
 --ghc-options -fllvm\
 --ghc-options -optlo-O3

Configuring GHCi with the following packages: 

when making flags consistent: warning:
    -O conflicts with --interactive; -O ignored.
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /tmp/ghci31252/ghci-script
Prelude> import Data.Array.Repa
Prelude Data.Array.Repa> import System.Random
Prelude Data.Array.Repa System.Random> randomList = randoms (mkStdGen 0)
Prelude Data.Array.Repa System.Random> shape = (Z :. 1000000)
Prelude Data.Array.Repa System.Random> array = fromFunction shape $ \(Z :. i) -> randomList !! i
Prelude Data.Array.Repa System.Random> sumP array
```

Still no dice:

[image]

I deeply appreciate any further assistance with this matter.

Comment: Is it compiled with the threaded runtime?

Comment: The README for repa literally has 3 sentences in it; there's no excuse for not having read it. One of those sentences is "Functions written with the Repa combinators are automatically parallel provided you supply +RTS -Nwhatever on the command line when running the program".

Comment: I disagree with the downvotes. Yes, the OP missed to turn on the threading runtime, as the docs suggest. But at least the question shows effort in diagnosing the issue. I wish all the questions on SO showed this much effort.

Comment: I updated the original question. Please let me know if I am still misunderstanding you.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, it appears that ghci ignores certain input options and therefore monadic computations like `sumP` will only use one CPU core. However, the purpose of this experiment was to use multiple cores for a personal project that I was working on, and I was successful in that objective. The key, I think, was adding `-with-rtsopts=-N` in my `.cabal` file under `ghc-options`. The final `ghc-options` are as follows:

```
executable write
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             Write.hs
  ghc-options:         -Odph 
                       -rtsopts 
                       -with-rtsopts=-N
                       -threaded 
                       -fno-liberate-case 
                       -funfolding-use-threshold1000 
                       -funfolding-keeness-factor1000 
                       -fllvm 
                       -optlo-O3
```

Comment: Um, what options is ghci supposed to have ignored? It looks like you never used e.g. `+RTS -N4` at all, which is the recommended way (like the README and the commenters said)!

Comment: I think the crucial thing that a lot of commenters are looking at is that even though in your question's update you indicate that you were using `-with-rtsopts=-N`, both how you've phrased this answer, as well as the `ghc-options` you are passing to `stack ghci` seem to indicate that you were missing that option until now, which is indicated in Repa's README. Note that `-with-rtsopts=-N` is the same as passing `+RTS -N` directly, which indicates to the runtime to use as many cores as are on the machine.

Comment: Note that just specifying `-threaded` isn't enough because that's a compile-time option that only turns on multi-core support; it enables the `-N$SOME_NUM_HERE` flag. RTS options are runtime options (RTS stands for runtime system) and hence can be changed for each different run of your program (one run you could limit the max # of cores to 3, another maybe 1)

Comment: Apologies! That was a type. As the screenshot proves, I did in fact pass `-with-rtsopts=-N` to ghci, but not to `ghc-options` in the cabal file. I figured that if it didn't work for ghci, it wouldn't work for the compiled code either. That assumption, it turns out, was wrong.